# How to get my navbar to fluidly contain the largest element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get my logo to fit inside my navbar without it "falling out" like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4T1B.png

The relevant code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img id="navbar-logo" src="/images/logo_only.png"></a>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
[[if .User]]
    <li><a id="currentUser" href="/account/home">[[.User.Username]]</a></li>
    <li><a href="/signout">Sign out</a></li>
[[else]]
    <li class="[[.SignupActive]]"><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
    <li class="[[.LoginActive]]"><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
    <!--li><a href="#">Support</a></li-->
[[end]]
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* ---------- NAVBAR STYLE -----------
----------------------------------- */

#navbar-logo {
height: 50px;
}
```

I've searched multiple places and I can't figure out for the life of my how to do this without messing around with height (of the navbar) manually. I'd like it to look as if the logo was the same height from the top and bottom of the navbar. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Is your logo floated?

Comment: Could you provide a Photoshop snapshot of your final goal? How much vertical space, if any, around the chevrons? Even better, take some time to copy paste your code in a JSFiddle, Plunkr or a Codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common occurrence in Bootstrap with logos, and you need more context, because there are other ways to do this, but based on your snippet of code, you can do this:

```
.navbar-brand{padding:0 !important}
#navbar-logo {
height:100%;
width:auto;
max-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a ton. I'll have to go and read about the !important tag.

Comment: !important will override any CSS declaration, no matter if it's declared AFTER your CSS . Remember CSS styles always shows in "cascades", so the later applied is the one that is used. The !important rule has to be used sparingly because if you try to affect that rule, it won't have any effect unless you add !important again. I've added !important because I'm pretty sure navbar-brand has an !important rule there, but try without it, if it works, then better, I wrote that code out of my head